# Horizontal scroll on a cellview

Tags: uitableview, ios5, cell, horizontal-scrolling

I want to do a horizontal scroll on a cell inside a table view, that has a vertical scroll. I have that app: http://www.realmacsoftware.com/clear/ like an example. I want to do something similar, in terms of interaction.

Do you have some ideas, about the best way to do that?

Comment: dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712554/horizontal-scrolling-uitableview

Comment: I don.t want to make a horizontal scrollable tableview, but a horizontal scroll on his cells. The tableview would have a vertical scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom cell (either using an XIB), or programatically. Then insert a custom UIView subclass in the cell, and handle gestures on that UIView. Sorry, this seems complex but there is no direct, built-in way to do this unless you customize the cell with your own UIView.

Comment: A UIVIEW inside a Cell seems legit. I will give it a try. tks!