# How to create an Custom picker?? Or

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to create an app that contains something like this image:

[image]

When the user changes the label it should change an image above..
There is more option after the number "24", like a picker.

I have the idea to implement an picker in horizontal mode, but I don t now how to change the design of it to be like the image (without the effect well).

Any one have an idea how to do that, or something that works like this???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: I am using the scrollview, however i don t know how to make the movement of the list to stop only below the arrow, not in the middle.. any idea?? thanks

Comment: Horizontal table views looks to be the key solution here. After searching for some posts, i am getting an impression that "easy table view's" could do this. Please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870680/horizontal-uitableview

Comment: thanks for the answer... but my problem is that I want the "contents" to have a fixed move, like the an picker,in that way I have always an item below the arrow

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter a `UIPickerView` object much so you should consider a rotated `UITableView` object. More than subclass, you will need to build a composite view that basically mirrors some of the methods of the `UITableView` object. And you will have to add appropriate methods that handle the selected value.

Comment: how i put the table view in a horizontal way??? and how i know which label is below the arrow??