# Both vertically and horizontally scrollable tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

i am displaying a large table in my uiview ...the problem is i need to scroll this tableview horizontally also.

- i tried to place the tableview in a scroll view.

  made the scrollview connected to the view outlet and connected the table to a tablview
  iboutlet

  made the scroll views size (320,460) and uitableviews size (1000,460)

but i am not able to scroll the table horizontally.is there a better way to accomplish this(ie display a wide table of width around 1000).

Comment: What about making the tables cell scrollable?

Comment: but in that case if i scroll a row,only that scrolls right.... i want to scroll it as a whole table.. just like we scroll a large webpage in webview

Comment: @himanshu i have not used any code here... everything done through interface builder ...only code is that of the uitableview delegate and datasource methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the UIScrollView contentSize property  through code and make sure that UIScrollView contentSize property will have the same height but it would have a greater width than tableView.

Answer (score 1):

See Same At below Link

[UITableView scroll both vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156573/uitableview-scroll-both-vertically-and-horizontally/9156646#9156646)