# How to have one cell by column in a UICollectionView?

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

In the same vein as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2870680/1670830), I would like to have a `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling and with only one item (cell) per column.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with this parameter (or maybe the other one; on this example, the collection view is in vertical mode):

[image]